# Get google profile image with firebase id

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I've been using firebase to make the login, it returns me a firebase's uid, that as I saw it's not possible of making the request to get the google id.

I know that the firebase account is a different account than Google but my question is: There is some possible way that I can use firebase account uid to get Google profile image without having to change my login method to log with Google+?

This is the URL to get the profile photo of Google is: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/profile/m/plus/v1/plus.people.get

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a users profile with their uid.
You can use

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(function(profile){...})
```

once you have the account you should be able to acces their profile with the firebase properties, in your case use the photoURL property.
Hope this helps
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users